# How to delete elements from a pandas dataframe column which is a series having list of values

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a pandas data frame having column which has lists in it. so i want if the number of elements in the list is greater than a variable MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH_TRAIN then delete the last ones

```
if MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH<MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH_TRAIN:
    data['padded_sequences'] = pad_sequences(data.sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH_TRAIN, padding='post', value=0).tolist()
else:
    data['padded_sequences'] = data['sequences'].str[:MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH_TRAIN]
```

Col A

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

after deletion

```
[1 2 3 ]
[1 2 3 ]
```

Comment: `df['Col A'].str[:3]`

Comment: Add your dataset and code here. Then. we can help.